# Teams meeting extend sidebar

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Using Teams Toolkit to create a custom tab app and it works. Unfortunately the app comes in the sidebar. Would it be possible to extend this sidebar or bring the app in center of the screen?

I have tried with share to stage feature but I cannot give the other user full control over my screen which is vital for my setup. Can anyone suggest what is the right way to this?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "DevTest",
        "full": "Full name for dev"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description of dev",
        "full": "Full description of dev"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "index0",
            "name": "App Tab",
            "contentUrl": "https://MyWeb/index_01.html",
            "websiteUrl": "https://MyWeb.de",
            "scopes": [
                "groupChat"
            ],
            "context": [
                "personalTab",
                "channelTab"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://studio-b12.de/downloads/Vossen/TeamsTab.html",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "context": [
                "channelTab",
                "privateChatTab",
                "meetingChatTab",
                "meetingDetailsTab",
                "meetingSidePanel",
                "meetingStage"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "https://MyWeb.de"
    ],
    "showLoadingIndicator": false,
}
```

[image: Teams]

Comment: We cannot extend the sidebar. You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). You can use [share to stage feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-apps-for-teams-meeting-stage?tabs=desktop). Share to stage allows users to share an app to the meeting stage from the meeting side panel in an ongoing meeting.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT yup I used share to stage feature and it works. But then another user cannot take control over my screen anymore. It is not available when I do share to stage.

Comment: The app sharing is interactive and collaborative. User can interact with the app being shared to stage but not with your entire screen. Please refer this for more info on app sharing capabilities depending on the tenant user type and participant roles in a meeting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/build-apps-for-teams-meeting-stage?tabs=desktop#get-app-content-stage-sharing-capabilities-api

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT basically I do need the user to interact with my whole screen. That is the motive. Right now when I press "share" button, it creates a new instance for the user and another instance for me. This is what I do not need.

Comment: It is currently not possible.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT would it be possible to add this feature? As we are anyway able to screenshare it so it won't be much of a difficulty to add "Access Control" right?

Comment: You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: yup already done. Thanks for your feedback. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/f5ca66f2-522c-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93, https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/c770acd5-7c2f-ee11-a81c-6045bd8534ad